# Multiplication of non-convex functions is also non-convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider that we have a set of non-convex functions $f_1, f_2, ...., f_n$. Is it also non-convex the multiplication of these functions? In other word, $f=f_1 \times f_2 \times...\times f_n$ is non-convex? Have anyone a reference article or book for this?

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample, let $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\sqrt x$.

See this answer: [Proving that multiplication of convex function is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147664/proving-that-multiplication-of-convex-function-is-convex)

Comment: Consider that the domain of $x$ in $f_1$ and $f_2$ is not negative. Therefore, the domain of $x$ is not negative and we can conclude that your example is not convex. The link is the inverse of my question.

Comment: Here is another example: $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=x^{2/3}$. The product is $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ which is convex.

Also, I know my link is the inverse but maybe you can get some ideas there.

Comment: Another source of information on this topic: https://www.ima.umn.edu/sites/default/files/2204.pdf